# Таблица виртуальных функций

Tags: c++, функции

прочитал про виртуальную таблицу и остались вопросы, помогите, пожалуйста.
Пусть есть класс иерархия :

```
class B1
{
public:
void f0() {}
virtual void f1() {}
int int_in_b1;
};

class B2
{
public:
virtual void f2() {}
int int_in_b2;
};

class D : public B1, public B2
{
public:
void d() {}
void f2() {}  // переопределяем B2::f2()
int int_in_d;
};
```

Правильно ли я понял, что схема памяти класса **D** будет утсроен так, что в ней будет указатель на виртулаьную таблицу класса **B1vtable** , и указатель на собственную таблицу  **Dvtable**?

в вики приводится псевдо-код , который компилятор напишет для вызова виртулаьной функции :

```
*((d->B1vtable)[0])(d)    // d->f1();
*((d->Dvtable)[0])(d+8)  // d->f2();
*((B2vtable)[0])(d+8)   // d->B2::f2();
```

схема вызова функции по ее указателю так устроена, что *(d)* , *(d+8)* - ее аргументы. Но эти функции не принимают аргументов, что тут не так?

Таблица памяти :

```
 d:
 +0: указатель на ТВМ D (для B1)
 +4: значение int_in_b1
 +8: указатель на ТВМ D (для B2)
 +12: значение int_in_b2
 +16: значение int_in_d

 Всего: 20 Bytes.

 ТВМ D (для B1):
 +0: B1::f1()  // B1::f1() не переопределена

 ТВМ D (для B2):
 +8: D::f2()   // B2::f2() переопределена D::f2()
```

Comment: Каноническая ссылка: http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Правильно ли я понял, что схема памяти класса D будет утсроен так, что в ней будет указатель на виртулаьную таблицу класса B1vtable , и указатель на собственную таблицу Dvtable?

Таблиц виртуальных функций и указателей на них в Стандарте языка нет, потому как там и что зависит от компилятора. Это просто де-факто стандартная реализации механизма виртуальных функций.

Захочет компилятор - будет несколько указателей, захочет - будет 1 указатель и для каждого класса создаст новую таблицу с изменением адресов перегруженых в этом классе вирт. методов.

Comment: ок, понял. допустим в **D** создадим еще одну вирт. функцию **f3()**. Тогда любой же компилятор будет обязан создать еще одну вирт. таблицу для нее ?

Comment: Новая таблица создана не будет, адрес метода **f3()** будет помещён в **Dvtable**.

Comment: да , вы правы, я туплю. А зачем тогда передавать в функцию аргумент **d** : ***((d->B1vtable)[0])(d)**

Comment: Видимо это указатель ``this``, а d+8 - указатель на один из базовых классов, нам же нужно передать правильный указатель this для соответствующего метода.

Comment: да, вы снова правы:). НО мне кажется там ошибка : при вызове переопределенного метода класса **D** мы должны передать ему другой **this**-указатель :

      *((d->Dvtable)[0])(d+16)  // d->f2();

Comment: Почему +16?

Если не ошибаюсь, то Стандарт не оговаривает как относительно друг друга должны располагаться объекты класса при наследовании. Важно то, что:

1) при вызове ``d->f2()`` в функцию должен попасть указатель ``this`` именно на ``D``, т.к. этот метод переопределён в этом классе

2) при вызове ``d->f1()`` в функцию должен попасть указатель ``this`` на базовый класс ``B1``, т.к. в ``D`` нет переопределения этого метода

Comment: 16 - это сдвиг относительно первого байта. Посмотрите на таблицу памяти : **d+16** - это начало данных класса **D** в таблице памяти. Я не прав?

Comment: Если +16 это сдвиг до D, тогда правы.